# Can I schedule a file to be uploaded from my server to dropbox?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

A client of mine wants a scheduled file upload to Dropbox on a weekly basis from his server.

We compiled survey data and I have a script in Laravel 5 which produces a CSV file weekly. He wants this file scheduled to be uploaded to his clients Dropbox at the same time every week.

Does the Dropbox API allow for this?

Comment: Yes, it does allow for that. Ten seconds in Google finds https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Laravel schedule command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) which will do the job using `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Dropbox side of this, yes, Dropbox does offer an API you can use to programmatically upload files. As mentioned in a comment on the question, for Dropbox API v1 the endpoint is:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put

There's an official PHP SDK you can use here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php

The respective method in that is `uploadFile`:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_uploadFile

For Dropbox API v2 the endpoint is:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

There currently isn't an official PHP SDK for Dropbox API v2.